# Education on CV

Tags: resume, education

I'm from Finland where I am currently an IT student. I'm updating the English version of my CV and need some assistance in mentioning my specializations. I've read on Wikipedia about Major/Minor, but it seems that the American system is different than what we have.

My Education:

-Bachelor of Business Administration qualification
-Information Technology Degree Programme
-Software Developer specialization

How should I display my education on a CV?

Comment: Made some slight edits to try make this less localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Lists most recent degree first (reverse chronological order).
- Always includes degree and major field of study, date of graduation
  (or "expected graduation date" if you are still enrolled), school,
  city and location.
- List professional certifications, studies abroad, titles of courses
  relevant to the job you are seeking, minor courses of study or
  "concentrations," academic honours you earned (these may be listed in
  a separate section if there are many of them), special skills (i.e.
  computer skills which may also be listed in a separate section).
- Do not list your high school.

Your [Major](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Major) would be determined by the following definition -

> *** **Of or relating to the field of academic study in which a student specializes.*****

This being your Major is your Degree as you majored in Information Technology

Comment: Thank you for answering. But that's exactly the question.
Term "Major" is difficult for my understanding.
So, based on provided info, is my major Information Technology or Software development??

Comment: Made a change to my answer to reflect this @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Express it exactly as you have:The degree earned, the name and location of the school, and when it was earned. Some will debate about including the date earned, but most applications ask for it.

When a CV/resume is used across international borders it is likely that the person reading the CV doesn't have a clue about the quality of the school or the quality of the exact program. It is even true if the degree is earned in the same country.

Frequently the person reading that part of the CV is trying to ascertain if the you have the equivalent of a bachelors, masters or doctorate.

Regarding the the term Information technology or Software development: Even in the US these terms have no specific meaning. I have seen US high schools put all programming classes under the Math department, the Business department, or group them with all computer classes under an IT department.

Some US colleges have IT majors and Computer Programing and Software Engineering with great overlaps between the classes. The big difference may be in the amount of math required, and that can't be determined by the title.